# How to run py.test against different versions of python?

Tags: python, pytest

Is it possible to run `py.test` with different versions of python without plugins (like `xdist`) or `tox`?

Answer (score 23):

The simplest way to do it is by running the pytest module directly with `-m`, for example:

```
python2.6 -m pytest
```

Note that you have to have pytest installed for *that version* of Python. In addition, you need to install all pytest plugins that you are using for *that version* of Python too.

Answer (score 6):

You can create a standalone pytest script with

```
py.test --genscript=mypytest
```

and then do

```
pythonXY mypytest
```

to run tests with a particular python version.

You do not need to install pytest for that particular python version as pytest is completely contained in the "mypytest" script.

Comment: `--genscript` is no longer supported since `pytest 3.0.0`

Answer (score 2):

[VirtualEnv](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv) is done to handle those case.

> virtualenv is a tool to create isolated Python environments.

Using virtualenv, you will be able to create multiple environements, each one with one plugin you want.

Comment: Note that you have to install pytest in your virtualenv, rather than invoking the version you might have installed in your regular PATH.

Comment: I installed pytest in my virtual environment but it still uses wrong version :/ $ which pytest $ /home/nurp/.envs/test/bin/pytest
 replace pytest with py.test just worked. I have no idea when that changed. pytest used to work a while ago...

Answer (score 0):

Using xdist plugin this can be [easily done](https://pytest.org/latest/xdist.html):

`py.test -d --tx popen//python=pythonX`

runs python version X (2 or 3).

---

Since this is the first google result of `"pytest test multiple versions"` I'm posting this, nevertheless I realize this is not an answer to OP's question of how to do this without plugins.